# i want to import FB event data in facebook php SDK

Tags: php, facebook

```
try {
      $response = $fb->get('/350717478732426/?fields=id,name,interested_count,start_time,end_time,owner,place,attending_count,cover,guest_list_enabled,type,updated_time,description,event_times,ticket_uri', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    $graphNode    = $response->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    echo "
";
        print_r($graphNode);
    echo "";
```

Comment: this is my code,user access token is used in this

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code.

If you have either clicked "duplicate" in your product category or clicked the "copy to a new draft" inside a product's "edit page", you will see this error message. To fix the issue is very simple. You will just need to "Reset Facebook metadata" inside the new product listing before you click Update. You will find this link inside the "edit page" of the product you are receiving the error. It should be between the Product Tags and the Product Image on the right hand side.

If the above does not work it a likely as issue with permissions.

Comment: which permission